# Replace entry in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Is there any way to replace a value in an ArrayAdapter

```
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
..
..
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    String name = MPGDeviceDetailsControl.getDeviceDetails(this, device.getAddress(), device.getName()).getDisplayName();
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(name + "\n" + device.getAddress());
}
```

If I wish to replace one of the entries is there any way of doing it without deleting and reinstering.
Problem with that is that it puts it at the bottom.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this should work to replace items

```
int i = 0;
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    String name = MPGDeviceDetailsControl.getDeviceDetails(this, device.getAddress(), device.getName()).getDisplayName();
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.remove(name); // has to copy all items back 1 position
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.insert(name + "\n" + device.getAddress(), i); // copy them +1 again
    i++;
}
```

but it would be more efficient, if you have access to the List that is backing this ArrayAdapter and replace / modify that.

```
ArrayList<Strign> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name, mList);

// setup
mList.add...
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

// change something
mList.set(i, newValue); // just a replace, no copy
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to replace the display value without reinserting and using nested adapters. Simply change original collection and call adapter's notifyDatasetChanged()

```
//adapter initialization
MyClass[] someArray = ... ;
ArrayList<Strign> adapter = new ArrayList<String>(context, R.layout.item_layout, someArray);

//change something
someArray[i] = newValue;
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

It's pretty much the same as zapl's answer except it doesn't use nested adapters. It should work the same when the adapter is initialized with List but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score -4):

No You can replace without deleting or reinserting.

Comment: Please let us know how to do that.